# How to show Newton's method has quadratic convergence rate with an example?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Newton's method has a quadratic convergence under some conditions. However, I do not know how to show the quadratics convergence using an example.

To illustrate this, say 
$f(x) = \cos(x)- x^3$   and first guess $0.5$.

$n_1 = 1.112141637097$

$n_2 = 0.909672693736$

$n_3 = 0.867263818209$

$n_4 = 0.865477135298$

$n_5 = 0.865474033111$

But how can I show the rate of reduction of error when they all have the same number of digits？ how can I know which digits are accurate which are not? I am confused.

Comment: Calculate further at least to 9th iteration and more decimals. Then higlight the last figure in each row, which still match the next one.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you don't know the value of a root $x^*$, so you can't compute the errors $|x_k - x^*|$. The trick is to use the values $f(x_k)$. Because by definition, $f(x^*) = 0$, a first-order Taylor expansion of $f$ about $x^*$ tells you that
$$
  f(x_k) \approx f'(x^*) (x_k - x^*).
$$
Thus, assuming $f'(x^*) \not = 0$, you get
$$
  \frac{|f(x_{k+1})|}{|f(x_k)|} \approx \frac{|x_{k+1} - x^*|}{|x_k - x^*|},
$$
and you will observe quadratic convergence by looking at the values of $|f(x_k)|$, or at the ratios $|f(x_{k+1}) / f(x_k)|$.
In your example, starting from $x_0 = 0.5$, I observe the iterates and function values

```
x                       f(x)
5.000000000000000e-01   7.525825618903728e-01
1.112141637097273e+00  -9.328201795040982e-01
9.096726937368068e-01  -1.387540393506104e-01
8.672638182088165e-01  -5.393998041341219e-03
8.654771352982646e-01  -9.333106352094056e-06
8.654740331109566e-01  -2.810629506910800e-11
0.8654740331109566
```

The second column shows quadratic convergence ($10^{-3}$, $10^{-6}$, $10^{-11}$).

If you didn't observe quadratic convergence in the second column, that would tell you that $f'(x*) \approx 0$.